# Regex statement that matches an optional character into the same group

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Regex sandbox:

https://regex101.com/r/nAhuot/1

I need to group floats with ints. The keyword here is the same group. I can match beyond the decimal point like so:

```
(\d+)?(.)?(\d+)[ \t]+NUM(\d) <--- Regex to match beyond the decimal
(\d+)[ \t]+NUM(\d) <---- Regex to match up to the decimal
```

This is the text:

```
1.5707963267949         NUM0 ;
0                       NUM1 ;
0                       NUM2 ;
0                       NUM3 ;
0                       NUM4 ;
0                       NUM5 ;
```

The expected result is to have 2 groups within the regex, look like this:

```
(1.5707963267949,NUM0),(0,NUM1),(0,NUM2),(0,NUM3),(0,NUM4),(0,NUM5)
```

My solution makes multiple groups, how can I make it to group into only one group?

Comment: I need a regex statement that is able to match floats and ints into the same group. Key being into the same group. The 'optional character' here is the decimal point. It can be there, and sometimes it wont.

Comment: And you already have shown us one, why don't you use that one?

Comment: @mkrieger1 my solution makes multiple groups, I need it to group into only one group.

Anubhava and Insync got it, thank you!

Comment: A group can only match a contiguous substring.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[ \t]+(NUM\d)\b` https://regex101.com/r/RN8PXJ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure why the answer was wiped from the comments, but this is what worked:

```
((?:\-)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[ \t]+NUM(\d+)
```

Thank you to the user who solved it, lost his username

Comment: Just `(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)[ \t]+NUM(\d+)` would be good enough